# How can I send my tokens to my contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I want my contract to use my token.
So I coded it like this. first my token code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Elena is ERC20{
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name,symbol){
        // mint 1000 token
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000*10**18);
    }
}
```

and my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "./myToken.sol";

contract FundingTest{
    uint public constant MINIMUM_AMOUNT = 1 ether;
    address myToken;
    IERC20 private _currencyContract;

    constructor(address _myToken){
        myToken = _myToken;
        _currencyContract = IERC20(myToken);
    }


    function funding(uint sendMoney) public payable {
        _currencyContract.approve(msg.sender, sendMoney*10**18);
        _currencyContract.approve(address(this),_currencyContract.totalSupply());
        _currencyContract.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), sendMoney*10**18);
    }

    function currentBalance() public view returns(uint256){
        return _currencyContract.balanceOf(address(this));
    }
}
```

Token issuance is confirmed. But this kind of error happens
[image]

please help me

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to authorize your `FundingTest` to spend your tokens, by calling the `approve` function of the `Elena` token directly, with the address of the `FundingTest` contract and the amount you want to allow it to spend. Then, the `FundingTest` contract will be able to spend the tokens, which is what the `funding()` is trying to do.

Also, you could send all your tokens to the `FundingTest` contract directly by calling the `transfer` function in the Elena contract, indicating the address of the `FundingTest` as the recipient, and the amount you want to send it.

Calling the `approve` function on `_currencyContract.approve(msg.sender, sendMoney*10**18);`, the contract is the one approving the sender to spend the contract's token. This is not what you want. You want to allow the contract to spend the sender's tokens. And you cannot do that from the contract. You need to do it directly, calling the `Elena`'s `approve` function directly.

Look at the following screenshot from Remix where I deployed both contracts. I need to call the `approve` function of the `Elena` contract directly, with the address of the `FundingTest` token and the amount I'm allowing it to spend. The `FundingTest` cannot approve itself as the spender of your tokens, so you cannot do that from the `FundingTest` contract. You need to do it directly from the `Elena` contract.

[image]

Notice how the `FundingTest` contract is deployed at address: 0xFDDbd99fCf252dB25CCC89CC209c0218C5c5aB6D

While the `Elena` token is deployed at address: 0xe701Cc3Bdcc2D86Bd5Bb161eE5F929eA4Dd31e84

So, I call the `approve` function of the `Elena` token with the `FundingTest` contract address like this:

```
Elena.approve(FundingTestAddress, amountToAllowToSpend);
```

Like:

```js
Elena.approve(0xFDDbd99fCf252dB25CCC89CC209c0218C5c5aB6D, 100000000000000000000000);
```

Since you are calling the `Elena` contract directly (not from the `FundingTest` contract), then the `msg.sender` in the `Elena.approve` function will be you, your address, and thus it will authorize the `FundingTest` to spend your tokens.

After that, you can then call the `FundingTest.funding()` function and it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you. But I cat`t understand about approve function. th function request argument amount. What is this?

Comment: The ERC20 tokens have an `approve` function to allow someone else to spend your tokens on your behalf. Your `Elena` token inherits that `approve` function. Just call it. https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20

Comment: You are angel. Thank you

Comment: I took your advice and modified the funding() function. But the same error occurs. Why?You can check the modified code in the revised article. I'm sorry to bother you

Comment: Check the update of my answer, and get your code back to what it was before.